# I am trying to pass values from one page to another but the values aren't showing up. Any ideas?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

Sorry folks for this simple-minded question.

I am trying to pass values from dateList page called instruments.aspx to another page called registras.aspx.

So far, I can't see the values.

What am I doing wrong?

Here is the one line code from instruments.aspx:

```
<asp:HyperLink ID="hypG103" runat="server" Text="Sign up for this class" navigateurl='<%# String.Format("registras.aspx?loc={0}&cos={1}", Eval("COS"), Eval("LOCKERS")) %>' Target="_blank"   />
```

This is how I am trying to get the values loaded to registras.aspx page.

On markup, I have:

```
 <form id="form1" runat="server">
  COS:<asp:TextBox ID="txtCOS" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
  Lockers:<asp:TextBox ID="txtloc" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>

 <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Insert Record" OnClick="Button1_Click" />
 <br />
 <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text=""></asp:Label>
</form>
```

On codebehind:

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)
        Dim COS As String = Request.QueryString("cos")
        txtCOS.text = COS
        Dim loc As String = Request.QueryString("loc")
        txtloc.text = loc

End Sub
```

These values are notloading on markup.

Thanks very much in advance

Comment: Verify in your link you're seeing `registras.aspx?cos=xx&loc=xx`

Comment: Yes, I can see the values on address bar @tymeJV

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out the problem.

I was missing the Handles

As soon as I added `Handles Me.Load` to pageLoad() event, it worked.

Answer (score 0):

one thing that could be happening is that you don't have tostring() in the page load try

Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)

```
    Dim COS As String = Request.QueryString("cos").ToString()

    txtCOS.text = COS

    Dim loc As String = Request.QueryString("loc").ToString()

    txtloc.text = loc
```

End Sub

Comment: Well, @onikirimaru, when I do that, I get error that String is not a member of 'String'. I don't know what that means.

Comment: I won't ToString every QueryString("...") because QueryString("...") could be Nothing when it's not specified in the URL, and hence produces error. Other than that, QueryString() is already of type String.